# React Typescript ie18next: Loading translations from an API

Tags: reactjs, typescript, i18next

I have worked previously on using i18next to load translations from static json files. But now in my project, I want to load all the translations from the API. how to do that? Also how to change translation on language change switch? Can we change URL with selected locale with i18next? I have researched a lot but haven't found any answer suitable to my query. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can load translations dynamically after initializing i18next.
Please refer to the code below and add the second part at the appropriate place.

```js
import i18next from 'i18next';

i18next.init({ resources: {} });

// Part where you need to add after you make the API call. 
i18next.addResourceBundle('en', 'namespace1', {
  key: 'hello from namespace 1'
});
```

As for switching languages, you could use the default function to switch languages.

Comment: @G Sriram: thanks for your answer, it's very helpful. I tried this, only confusion i have is, in the resources section we use namespaces and link the json files which hold our translations. But when all the translations are loading from api call, then in that like shown in your code, resources object will be empty?

Comment: It'll be empty till the translations are loaded, and once it's loaded you can make the addResourceBundle function call.